# Temporarily pause scrolling on an ItemsControl as new items are added in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I have an observablecollection log which inserts new entries into the top in a Windows Universal App. I let users view the log by binding it to an itemscontrol. If there are a lot of incoming updates in the log it can be hard to use because it will keep scrolling as new items are added. I'd like to add a pause button to suspend scrolling, or perhaps updating.

I see beginupdate and endupdate, but those only seem to apply to WPF controls. I'm also considering something in my log class to turn off raising the propertychanged event, but I'm not sure how to seamlessly update everything missed when the itemscontrol is unpaused?

Comment: You could just add a level of indirection where updates are fed into a queue when the list is paused. Don't update the primary list. When it's unpaused, just move the queue to the bound list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution ... I put the itemscontrol into a scrollviewer instead of the scrollviewer in the ItemContainerStyle.

So basically I'm keeping track of the virtual size of the scrollviewer and tracking the log collection. When paused and the collection changes, move the vertical offset of the scrollviewer by how much it just grew, with the animation disabled so the move isn't visible, so it visibly remains in the same place.

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Entries.CollectionChanged += Entries_CollectionChanged;
        this.LogItemsControl.ItemsSource = Log.Entries;
        lastExtentHeight = this.ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight;
    }

    private void Entries_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lastExtentHeight = this.ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight;

        if (scrollingPaused)
        {
            double sizeGrown = ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight - pausedExtentHeight;

            pausedVerticalOffset += sizeGrown;
            pausedExtentHeight = ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight;

            this.ScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, pausedVerticalOffset, 1, true);
        }
    }

    private void PlayPauseAppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (scrollingPaused)
        {
            // UnPause
            scrollingPaused = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Pause
            pausedVerticalOffset = this.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
            pausedExtentHeight = lastExtentHeight;

            scrollingPaused = true;
        }
    }
```